# upload data in azure blob via a timetrigger azure function written in Python

Tags: python, triggers, azure-functions, blob, azure-storage

I have written a time trigger azure function that triggers a Kafka steam  on an hourly basis and fetches data from there. Now I want to upload that data (JSON files) to azure blob storage. I am looking for some reference code in python to do the same.

Comment: Follow this link for Azure Function to automate the process of extracting data on a scheduled basis  and change the code for JSON file as it has given for CSV file : https://tanthiamhuat.files.wordpress.com/2020/05/documentations-for-creating-azure-functions-for-timer-trigger-using-python-lanuage.pdf

Comment: Have a look on this link for Azure Function to automate the process of extracting data on a scheduled basis and change the code for JSON file as it has given for CSV file and upload to the Azure-blob Storage Complete Step is provided in this link : https://tanthiamhuat.files.wordpress.com/2020/05/documentations-for-creating-azure-functions-for-timer-trigger-using-python-lanuage.pdf